# Ruby Datamapper connection with SSL to MariaDB on Amazon RDS

Tags: ruby, ssl, amazon-rds, ruby-datamapper

How do I establish a ruby Datamapper connection to MariaDB on Amazon RDS with SSL?

Here's what I did:

A non-SSL connection works when testing with:

```rb
uri = 'mysql://user:pass@host:port/db_name'
connection = DataObjects::Connection.new(uri)
=> #<DataObjects::Mysql::Connection:0x000056179a3a5921

connection.secure?
=> false
```

According to the [MySQL datamapper wiki](https://github.com/datamapper/do/wiki/MySQL), an ssl connection requires the following options: `:ssl_ca, :client_key, and :client_cert`.

This would result in the following code:

```rb
uri = 'mysql://user:pass@host:port/db_name?'
ssl_opts = 'ssl[ssl_ca]=file&ssl[client_key]=file&ssl[client_cert]=file'

connection = DataObjects::Connection.new(uri + ssl_opts)
connection.secure?
=> false
```

However the only files get is the [RDS combind CA bundle](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem), refered from the [RDS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MariaDB.html#MariaDB.Concepts.SSLSupport)

I do not have a client_cert at all.

Connecting with the mysql client on cli works with SSL:

```
mysql --ssl -h host -u user -p pass db_name
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 1638
Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB MariaDB Server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one parameter required: `:ssl => {:ca_cert => 'pem_file'}`.

However it looks like using uri string for configuration does not work. The reason is a limitation in Addressable::Uri. It cannot handle query strings which aim to represent hashes with more than 1 level.

The good news is that it works using `DataMapper.setup` with a config Hash:

```rb
DataMapper.setup(:default, 
    :adapter  => 'mysql', 
    :user     => 'user',
    :database => 'db_name',
    :host     => 'host',
    :password => 'pass',
    :ssl => { 
        :ca_cert  => '/path/to/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In doc

https://github.com/datamapper/do/wiki/MySQL

It also says

- ## as tested only ca_cert was required to connect to RDS.

So try adding only ca_cert path and do a test

Comment: Thanks. This wiki section is obvious about the option.
Unfortunately it does not work using `ssl[ca_cert]=path_to_cert` uri.

However if I use `DataMapper.setup` with `:ssl => {:ca_cert  => '/path/to/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'}` option then it works

Comment: After debugging for a while I came to the conclusion that the reason is a limitation of `Addressable::Uri`. It seems that it cannot handle query strings which aim to represent hashes with more than 1 level. I tested by using it successively in both directions: 1. Create the query string from the hash. 2. Use the result to recreate the hash. Result was `{"ssl"=>"{:ca_cert=>\"/path/to/cert\"}"}` instead of `{"ssl"=>{:ca_cert=>"/path/to/cert"}}`